# Problem when passing an Object as a parameter of a function

Tags: javascript, object

I have problems with a function that expects an object as a parameter.
Apparently it assigns the properties only inside the function since outside the function it has no properties.

```
const makeUser = (name, age) => {
  return {
    name,
    age,
  };
};

let user;

const newUser = obj => {
  name = "userTester";
  age = 19;

  obj = makeUser(name, age);
  console.log(obj);
};

newUser(user);
console.log(user)
console.log(`El nombre del usuario es ${user.name} y tiene ${user.age} años.`);
```

Comment: You haven't assigned anything to the variable `user` when you pass it to `newUser()`.

Comment: It is assigned when reaching the line obj = makeUser(name, age)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what u want to do but maybe something like that? lol

```js
const makeUser = (name, age) => {
  return {
    name,
    age,
  };
};


const newUser = obj => {
  name = "userTester";
  age = 19;

  obj = makeUser(name, age);
  console.log(obj);
  return obj;
};

let user = newUser();

const modifyUser = ()=>{
  user.name = "José";
  user.age = 35;
}

console.log(user);
console.log(`El nombre del usuario es ${user.name} y tiene ${user.age} años.`);

modifyUser();
console.log(`El nombre del usuario es ${user.name} y tiene ${user.age} años.`);
```

Comment: I'm practicing Javascript, I wanted to see if you can modify an object with a function but apparently you can't XD. Also thanks for the answer

Comment: @DanielReyes, sure you can, just don't pass the value as an argument. Then the value  inside the function will be a copy of the original value. After that you should return the value to use it outside of the function. But you can mutate global variables if you just reassign them inside the function without passing them as arguments.

Comment: @DanielReyes sure you can, I have edited the answer with a modifyUser function which mutates the global user variable. Just as an example